# join 2 foreign key using subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

help me solve this, i am intended to join 2 table for 2 different foreign key within the same column, table snapshot provide below:

users table

[image: users table]

transactions table

[image: transactions table]

i want to return top 5 based on transactions amount from high-low alongside to display transactions id, investor id, investor name, borrower id, borrower name, amount

the following run properly but contains no investor name

```
select top 5 t.id,
    investor_id,
    borrower_id,
    username as BorrowerName,
    amount
    from transactions t join users u on t.borrower_id = u.id
    order by t.amount desc;
```

[minus investor name result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05MKz.png)
[image]

while if i do subquery resulting error

```
select top 5 t.id,
    investor_id,
    (select username from users join transactions on users.id = 
    transactions.investor_id) investorName,
    borrower_id,
    username BorrowerName,
    amount
     from transactions t join users u on t.borrower_id = u.id
     order by t.amount desc;
```

Comment: You should specify which database engine you're using. Also some desired results would help.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MS Access?

Comment: hi, iam using sql server, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select top 5 t.id,
       investor_id, ui.username as InvestorName,
       borrower_id, ub.username as BorrowerName,
       amount
  from transactions t 
  join users ub on t.borrower_id = ub.id
  join users ui on t.investor_id = ui.id   
 order by t.amount desc;
```

Comment: If you used it as the answer you can click the check box to indicate so.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want? Two joins on `users` table

```
SELECT TOP 5
  investor_id,
  investors.username InvestorName,
  borrower_id,
  borrowers.username BorrowerName,
  amount
FROM
  transactions
  INNER JOIN users investors ON (transactions.investor_id = investors.id)
  INNER JOIN users borrowers ON (transactions.borrower_id = borrowers.id)
ORDER BY
  amount desc;
```

I would recommend against using subqueries in this case, since the database will be forced to perform two sequential scans in a nested loop for each row.

Answer (score 0):

The Subquery must be *scalar*. i.e. return a single value, but you currently return a *result set*.

```
select top 5 t.id,
    investor_id,
    (-- Correlated Scalar Subquery, returns a single value
      select username 
      from users
      WHERE users.id = transactions.investor_id) investorName,
    borrower_id,
    username BorrowerName,
    amount
     from transactions t join users u on t.borrower_id = u.id
     order by t.amount desc;
```